# how to configure hostname to have identical name as subdomain?

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, subdomain, windows-server-2008-r2

I've accomplished the following easily on a unix system, but I don't manage to get the same configured on a MS Windows server:

`subdomain.example.org` is a zone, so that I can setup child hostnames like `host.subdomain.example.org`. Furthermore, `subdomain.example.org` is also an entry point to the subdomain and runs a webserver. For that purpose I create an `A record` that points to an IP address. That is, the hostname is identical with the subdomain name.

I don't seem to be able to reproduce this on the windows server. once I create the subdomain, I can't add the `A record`. What's the secret to getting this up and running?

Comment: Use blank `@` for name?

Comment: @dirt so I use `@` as the hostname in the subdomain?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, yes. Using `@` for the `name` value of an `A` record is for the root level of the zone in your case `@.subdomain.example` would define the IP of `subdomain.example.com` while `host.subdomain.example` would define the IP of `host.subdomain.example.com` (to go another level you could create host as zone and need `@.host.subdomain.example`)

Comment: @dirt I had to leave the name field empty and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating A records you can use the `@` symbol for the record name to indicate the parent record i.e. no record name. In your case this applies to subdomain zones (and beyond).

```
example.com = @ IN A 1.2.3.4  
www.example.com = www IN A 192.168.0.2
```

Example raw dns zone file:

```
$TTL    14400
$ORIGIN example.com.
@  1D  IN    SOA ns1.example.com.   hostmaster.example.com. (
                  2002022401 ; serial
                  3H ; refresh
                  15 ; retry
                  1w ; expire
                  3h ; minimum
                 )
       IN  NS     ns1.example.com. ; in the domain
       IN  NS     ns2.smokeyjoe.com. ; external to domain
       IN  MX  10 mail.another.com. ; external mail provider

@      IN  A      1.2.3.4   ; root record here would be value for example.com
ns1    IN  A      192.168.0.1  ;name server definition     
www    IN  A      192.168.0.2  ;web server definition
ftp    IN  CNAME  www.example.com.  ;ftp server definition

bill   IN  A      192.168.0.3
fred   IN  A      192.168.0.4
```